# paging in mdx query

Tags: mdx

Hello
i am giving row numbers to result using rank in mdx expression,now how can i restrict no. of rows retrieved that is i want first 10 rows and then i want another 10 rows and so on.So how can i apply such kind of paging in mdx expression itself

Answer (score 2):

What MDX engine are you using? Assuming Microsoft Analysis Services, this link will be helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx

TOPCOUNT is the keyword to examine, along with EXCEPT. The idea is you'll generate the set of the top 20, using TOPCOUNT, then EXCEPT the set of the top 10 - That'll give you numbers 11-20.